# How to get a specific date format using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, momentjs

I want to display the date clicked on in a specific format with localised strings, but although it shows the locale being set, the string I get is this:

```
Fri Jun 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

I would like to turn that into `Friday, 5. June 2015` with localised words.
On the clickEvents when I `console.log` the `target` I get the wrong string under `date._d` although under `date._locale` in date I see the localised stuff as well.
And I really don't understand how to change the format once I use `target.date.toDate()`.
My clickEvents in the CLNDR initiation:

```
clickEvents: {
    click: function (target) {
        $('.selected-date').text(target.date.toDate());
        console.log(target);
    }
},
```

Not sure if this is a Moment or CLNDR issue, but I am leaning towards Moment, since CLNDR is using it.

And this is what gets returned by the `console.log`:

```
{
  element: div.day.today.calendar-day-2015-06-05.calendar-dow-4,
  events: Array[0], date: Moment,
  date: Moment {
    _d: Fri Jun 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
    _f: "YYYY-MM-DD "
    _i: "2015-06-05"
    _isAMomentObject: true
    _isUTC: false
    _locale: Locale
    _pf: Object
    __proto__: Moment
    element: div.day.today.calendar-day-2015-06-05.calendar-dow-4
    events: Array[0]
    __proto__: Object
  }
}
```

Something like that. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really "roll your own" when it comes to localized dates because every locale has its own set of localized date strings. This is because different countries display their dates differently.

Why don't you want to use a country's format? If someone from another country uses your site, they will find a different date format odd.

You can get similar to what you're looking for with:

```
moment(date).format('dddd, LL');
```

For US, that would print

```
Thursday, September 4 1986
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was after. Thanks!